# How to switch between mapbox and google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet, mapbox

Why can´t switch basemap, between mapbox and googlemaps, I received this error in console.log():

```
leaflet-src.js:1981 Uncaught Error: Map container is already initialized.
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/pokaxperia/tooy7dsk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Added

```
        map.remove();
        $('.basemap').append(' <div id="map"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy the map container using the [`map.remove` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-remove). But first, you need to keep a reference to the map that you can refer to later. When you first create the map, assign it to a `var`:

```
var MBmap = L.mapbox.map('map', 'pokaxperia.pk657nfi').setView([19.432711775616433, -99.13325428962708], 12);
```

Then, when you switch to Google, you can destroy the Mapbox map. Put the following in your `_switchToGoogle` function:

```
if (MBmap) {
  MBmap.remove();
  MBmap = false;
}
```

And change your `_switchToMapbox` function to:

```
function _switchToMapbox() {
  if (!MBmap) {
    MBmap = L.mapbox.map('map', 'pokaxperia.pk657nfi').setView([19.432711775616433, -99.13325428962708], 12);
  }
}
```

Updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tooy7dsk/2/

Keep in mind that if all you are trying to do is switch background tiles (i.e. you don't need other Google maps functions like Streetview), you may be able to use the Google tiles in Mapbox with a [Leaflet plugin](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins).